# Why would my eventual output of this class ( a session wrapper ) turn up an empty array?

Tags: php, arrays, class, reference, wrapper

So I've written a series of classes - although the series is fairly irrelevant, and small. The 'SessionHandler' that I'm using extends an 'ArrayClass' that is simply that - a class that gets or sets from a provided array.

Here is the ArrayClass code:

```
class ArrayClass
{
    protected $TargetArray = null;

    public function __construct(&$TargetArray)
    {
        $this->TargetArray = $TargetArray;
    }

    public function __set($Key,$Value)
    {
        echo("Attempting to set value for key '$Key'...<br/>");

        if( !isset($this->TargetArray))
        {
            echo("TargetArray is not set. Creating and re-setting.<br/>");
            $this->TargetArray = array();
            return $this->__set($Key,$Value);
        }
        else
        {
            echo("Setting $Key to $Value...<br/>");
            $this->TargetArray[$Key] = $Value;
            echo("Value in TargetArray at key '$Key' set to " . $this->$Key . "<br/>");
            return $Value;
        }
    }

    public function __get($Key)
    {               
        echo("Attempting to retrieve a value for key '$Key'...<br/>");

        if( !isset($this->TargetArray))
            return null;
        else
            return $this->TargetArray[$Key];
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return var_export($this->TargetArray,true);
    }
}
```

Here is the class that inherits from this ( brief as it may be ):

```
class SessionHandler extends ArrayClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        session_start();

        parent::__construct($_SESSION);
    }

    public function End()
    {
        session_destroy();
    }   
}
```

And here is my use of all of the above:

```
$Session = new SessionHandler();
$Session->DebuggingKey = "12345";
echo($Session);
```

And my eventual output:

```
Attempting to set value for key 'DebuggingKey'...
Setting DebuggingKey to 12345...
Attempting to retrieve a value for key 'DebuggingKey'...
Value in TargetArray at key 'DebuggingKey' set to 12345
array ( )
```

The value gets set in the array. The value can be retrieved from the array. But when I attempt to echo the contents of the array, I return simply an array - seemingly empty.

Similarly; where I have another check in my debugger for the aforementioned DebuggingKey, I note that the session key has not been set:

```
public function IsActive()
{
    if( isset($_GET['debugging']) && $_GET['debugging'] != true )
        return false;
    else if( !isset($_SESSION['DebuggingKey']))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

This functions returns false.

Any thoughts? I'd hate to spin my wheels on this as it is mostly meant to ease a few characters that are repeated about a million times when building up something of the capacity that I am; so it's not entirely necessary - I'd just like to see it work... I'd like to wrap the GET, POST, and COOKIE variables in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also assign the object property as a reference to the `$TargetArray` argument:

```
public function __construct(&$TargetArray)
{
    $this->TargetArray =& $TargetArray;
}
```

Also, be aware that in PHP >= 5.4.0 there is already a `SessionHandler` class so you'll end up with:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class SessionHandler

Comment: Well lucky me I think I'm in PHP 5.3 and acting a fool! I'll take that under consideration. Is there a 'Session' class? ( I'll just look... ) And you absolutely nailed it - thank you. I don't often pass references in PHP - although I'm realizing I likely should more frequently.